# RecyclerView item content gets mixed up

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I've got a RecyclerView containing items with interactive content.
Every item contains a textview that's being updated every 5 seconds, but when there are more than 5 items in the RecyclerView, the data gets mixed up.

By example:

Correct:
| 1 - 100 |

| 2 - 283 |

| 3 - 382 |

When it gets mixed up:

| 2 - 283 |

| 1 - 100 |

| 3 - 382 |

It's kinda like that, it just gets mixed up.

This happens when I call de adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

My Adapter:

public class FavoritesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<Favorites> channels;
private Context context;

public FavoritesAdapter(Context context, List<Favorites> channels) {
    this.context = context;
    this.channels = channels;
}

@Override
public FavoritesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.favoriteitem_layout, viewGroup, false);
    FavoritesViewHolder pvh = new FavoritesViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FavoritesViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    if (Data.isConnected(context)) {
        Scheduler.getInstance().doAsync(new Scheduler.Task<Object, Channel>() {
            @Override
            public Channel run(Object... params) {
                return Methods.getData(channels.get(position).getChannelId(), channels.get(position).getChannelName(), true, context);
            }
        }, new Scheduler.Executable<Channel>() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Channel result) {

                if(result.getId() != "") {
                    if(!result.channelSubs.equalsIgnoreCase("-500_RTSS_ERROR")) {
                        holder.channelSubsView.setText(result.getSubs());
                        holder.channelTitleSubsView.setText(String.valueOf(channels.get(position).getChannelName()) + "'s Suscribers");
                        channels.get(position).setChannelSubs(result.getSubs());
                        dbHelper.updateFavorites(channels.get(position));
                    }
                    else {
                        holder.channelSubsView.setText(channels.get(position).getChannelSubs());
                        holder.channelTitleSubsView.setText(String.valueOf(channels.get(position).getChannelName()) + "'s Suscribers (Cached)");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    holder.channelSubsView.setText(channels.get(position).getChannelSubs());
                    holder.channelTitleSubsView.setText(String.valueOf(channels.get(position).getChannelName()) + "'s Suscribers (Cached)");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        holder.channelSubsView.setText(channels.get(position).getChannelSubs());
        holder.channelTitleSubsView.setText(String.valueOf(channels.get(position).getChannelName()) + "'s Suscribers (Cached)");
    }

    Picasso.with(context).load(channels.get(position).getChannelAvatar())
            .error(R.drawable.youtube_default_avatar)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.youtube_default_avatar)
            .into(holder.channelAvatarView);

    holder.channelCardView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    holder.channelCardView.setTag(holder);
}

View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FavoritesViewHolder holder = (FavoritesViewHolder) view.getTag();
        int position = holder.getPosition();

        Favorites channel = channels.get(position);
        if(Data.isConnected(context)) {
            Methods.getYouTubeData(channel.getChannelId(), channel.getChannelName(), channel.getChannelAvatar(), context);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_connection_no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return channels.size();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

public static class FavoritesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView channelCardView;
    TextView channelSubsView;
    TextView channelTitleSubsView;
    ImageView channelAvatarView;

    FavoritesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        channelCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channelCardView);
        channelSubsView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subsAmount);
        channelTitleSubsView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subsText);
        channelAvatarView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channelAvatarView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post your Adapter class please

Comment: Have you been successful in fixing it? I experience the same issue when I change the visibilty of text-views insinde a recycler-view's item and call notify-data-set-changed. This is so weird :-\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making an `asynchronous` call in `onBindViewHolder` so when the response of the async tasks comes, it reads **wrong** position from `public void onBindViewHolder(final FavoritesViewHolder holder, final int position)` because by that time position returned by `onBindViewHolder` has **changed**.

What you can do is, pass the position into `async task` as a parameter and deliver the same position in the result of the `async task`. That way call made for position **p** (say) will be applied to **p**.

Along with that, also try to use `getAdapterPosition` instead of `getPosition` (deprecated and creates confusion) on RecyclerViewHolder.

Comment: Not working either, I'll record a video to show you how it looks like.

Comment: Here's the video to see what's happening: https://youtu.be/9KU2iKtMPCE I will update the code asap.

Comment: The reason is the one provided in my answer. *By the time async task returns, **position** has been changed.*

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you are editing the order/ sorting of the initial list passed to the constructor of the adapter.

```
 List<Favorites> channels = getChannels();
 adapter = new FavoritesAdapter(context, channels);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
 //     edit or sort *channels*
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```